# Start powershell script with credentials of other user isn't working

Tags: powershell, credentials

I try to run script with higher permissions using `-credential` argument
When I try to do it using this part of code it shows that error which basically means that  **The name of the directory is incorrect.** Both script (that one that contain `start-process` and the `change_permissions.ps1` are in the same folder which is `\\srv1\Projekty\nowy_folder`.

[image]

Without `-credential` argument script works completely fine.

Here's whole script:

```
#gui
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$form_start = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form_start.Text = 'Tworzenie projektu'
$form_start.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(340,175)
$form_start.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$permission_button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$permission_button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(95,25)
$permission_button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(135,23)
$permission_button.Text = 'Przydziel uprawnienia'
$permission_button.add_Click({
    $username = "DOMAIN\USER"

    $password = "PASSWORD"
    
    $credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
   # Invoke-Command -FilePath "\\srv1\nowy_folder\change_permissions.ps1" -Credential $credentials
    Start-Process powershell -argumentlist '.\change_permissions.ps1' -workingdirectory "S:" #-Credential ($credentials) 

    # Using UNC instead of .\change_permissions.ps1 isn't working

})
$form_start.Controls.Add($permission_button)

#Code below is basically the same but runs other script which also isn't running properly

$create_folders_button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$create_folders_button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,75)
$create_folders_button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$create_folders_button.Text = 'Utwórz katalogi'
$create_folders_button.add_Click({
    $username = "DOMAIN\USER"

    $password = "PASSWORD"
    
    $credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
    
    Start-Process powershell -argument "C:\Projekty\nowy_folder\make_project_folder_with_subfolders.ps1" -Credential ($credentials) 
    # $form_start.close()
})
$form_start.Controls.Add($create_folders_button)

$form_start.Topmost = $true
$form_start.ShowDialog()
```

As you may noticed I tried the `invoke-command` as well. While using the `invoke-command` another error shows up: [image]

Do you have any solution to my problem?

Comment: To use ´Invoke-Command` with `-Credential` you need to specify `-ComputerName`. Does the user have access to the share?

Comment: Yes, he have access to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding such approach

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath c:\scripts\test.ps1 -ComputerName Server01
```

The FilePath parameter specifies a script that is located on the local computer. The script runs on the remote computer and the results are returned to the local computer.

if your file is locally saved, then you can try:

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath $localPath -computername srv1 -Credential $credentials
```

or you can use full path with such approach:

```
Invoke-Command -computername srv1 -scriptblock { \\srv1\nowy_folder\change_permissions.ps1} -Credential $credentials
```

or you can use direct path

```
 Invoke-Command -computername srv1 -scriptblock { c:\scripts\change_permissions.ps1} -Credential $credentials
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to do it without using winrm?
My main goal is to run script from network share as a domain user using local machine